# Need help in understanding this loop

Tags: python, logic

```
for k in range (1, len(str)):
    for i in range (0, (len(str)-k + 1)):
        j = i + k-1
        X[i][j] = 0
```

I am looking at line 2, line 3 and going crazy. Appreciate the help

to add more info, I have done the research and it basically calculates j so that X[i][j] can be filled. But what kind of logic is being deduced to calculate j is what I dont get
when k is 1 then
0, 0
1,1
2,2 etc is accessed
when k is 2 then
0,1
1,2
2,3 is accessed.
Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: The logic, what is it trying to do at each line. I added the next line which is basically filling the 2d list. But am lost on the logic to calculate j and the range of i

Comment: Have you tried printing `j` to see if there's a pattern?

Comment: it goes 0,0; 1,1; 2,2; etc. then 0,1;1,2 to fill the slots at those indices. But I am not getting the logic on how j is being achieved ie an explanation

Comment: The first time through the loop, `k=1`, so `k-1=0`, so `j = i`. The second time, `k=2`, so `k-1=1`, so `j = i+1`. And so on like that.

Comment: Depending on how `k,i,j` are used later in the loop - with a little thought - the ranges in the for loop expressions might be a little better expressed.

Answer (score -1):

In nested for loops, you always start with the inner and move your way out. In order to answer this question, I am going to set values to len(str) -> 4.

This is how the loop is going to work:

```
k=1, i=0
k=1, i=1
k=1, i=2
k=1, i=3
k=2, i=0
k=2, i=1
k=2, i=2
k=3, i=0
k=3, i=1
```

For each iteration of the outer loop we go through all the iterations for the inner loop.

Comment: I understand the inner loop to outer loop concept. But I am trying to understand the logic of calculating j from both the loops.